# Google Analytics: Core Reporting API measure bounce rate on a set of pages?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Can I use the Core Reporting API to measure bounce rate for a specific set of pages?

I have page urls for 50k pages in my website that I want to measure the bounce rate for. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's possible. You can always test queries using the [Google Analytics Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/). Here is an example of what your query would look like:

[image]

Comment: How do I specify the 50K pages in my set to the query?

Comment: My website has more than 1M pages and by default google returns a sampled set.

Comment: Create either a filter or segment for the pages you want to see. If you are running into sampling issues, try using a smaller date range.

Comment: I need to analyze a specific set of pages. It is more like my test set. It is not pages in a date range. Do you think there is any way to specify a particular page url and get analytics on it using the Core Reporting API?

Comment: you can set the sampling level in your request.  this will not work with the query explorer it doesn't support it an issue request has been created for that.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#samplingLevel